# Silverlight DataGrid - Customizing Group Header Text with info from items contained within

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have restyled the DataGridRowGroupHeader on my datagrid because I want to change the text it displays.
What I want is for it to summarize the data that it holds in its group.
(Specifically code should be able to check all the items held in the collection to find the one with the oldest date).

I am having trouble though with trying to access the items in the collection.
I was trying using a converter in the RowGroupHeader where it renders the text - but the collection always comes back as empty.

```
<sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles> 
        <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader"> 
            <Setter Property="Template"> 
        <!-- All the other spield from the default template, leading to below where the header text is rendered --> 

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,1"> 
            <TextBlock x:Name="PropertyNameElement" Margin="4,0,0,0"/> 
            <TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemCountElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ItemCountVisibility}"/> 
            <TextBlock x:Name="oldest" Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, ConverterParameter=Orders}" /> 
        </StackPanel>
```

And my converter is looking like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
{ 
    CollectionViewGroup cvg = value as CollectionViewGroup; 

    if (cvg.Items.Count==0) 
        return "Test Fails"; 
    else 
        return FindOldestObjectInCollection(cvg.Items); 
}
```

The CollectionViewGroup above is always empty - I was lead to beleive it should contain all the items in the group.
(Group created as a PagedCollectionView).
Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to implement a similar feature in an application. Are you sure that CollectionViewGroup.Items is filled when your converter is runned? It implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.items.aspx), and therefore could change after group creation.

You should therefore use another implementation, and bind to the Items property directly, as I have done myself:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock x:Name="PropertyNameElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding PropertyNameVisibility}"/>
      <TextBlock x:Name="ItemCountElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ItemCountVisibility}"/>
      <local:TendencyUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The XAML above works in my case.

Comment: Any ideas how I can just pass over the items in the 'Current Group' and not the whole collection every time? I cannot find the items purely in the current group, even with the name being passed over to the control.

Comment: the items property available in the group header context already contains only group items.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed [Items] was the ItemsSource I was using to populate the datagrid. didnt realise it was a property in itself.